# How to insert Doxygen html pages inside a flask generated web page

Tags: html, css, flask, doxygen

I own a small website generated by Flask.
I want to add a page containing Doxygen html pages.
The rendering is poor, it lacks the links (js ?) and the css.

As Doxygen generates its own css and js files, I think this is the reason why the rendering is incomplete.
I tried to copy the css and js in the static directory, then adding the links in the index.html Doxygen files, but still the same issue.

Do you have an idea of how to insert it in the flask website ?

Thanks
[image: Doxygen Rendering]

[image: Flask rendering]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Probably you should add the content of the doxygen generated html directory and its subdirectories. From Flask (what is that?) you should "call" the doxygen generated html/index.html.

Comment: Also you show show us what you see and mention which version of doxygen you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is exactly what I have done but the css/js from Dowygen are not loaded. I tried to copy them into the static directory but still does't work

Comment: The used doxygen version 1.9.1 is already a bit older the current doxygen version is 1.9.8. The image shown is as I would expect it, what is the problem?

Comment: The first image is Dowygen generated html output in local, the second the same integrated in my Flask website, it is not the same rendering, and there is no links to navigate in the second case.